# Mac Safari 7 Rendering Issue scrollLeft() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, scroll

I created a dynamic table that scrolls left and right, has resizable columns, has a fixed header, etc. This table works great on EVERY browser I've tried. Even IE8 looks good (missing features, but still good).

This issue arises when I try to view the table in Safari 7.0.4 on my Macbook.

Attached is what is should look like (the fixed header is on the bottom for demonstration purposes):

[image]

when you scroll, the fixed header, body, and fixed scrollbar all are connected via some jQuery `scrollLeft()` functions (scroll one, scroll all):

```
var tableHeaderSpace = $('.table-full-wrap-space'),
    tableHeader = $('.table-full-wrap-header'),
    tableBody = $('.table-full-wrap-body'),
    tableScroll = $('.table-full-wrap-scroll');

tableScroll.bind('scroll', function() {
    tableHeader.scrollLeft(tableScroll.scrollLeft());
    tableBody.scrollLeft(tableScroll.scrollLeft());
});

tableHeader.bind('scroll', function() {
    tableScroll.scrollLeft(tableHeader.scrollLeft());
    tableBody.scrollLeft(tableHeader.scrollLeft());
});

tableBody.bind('scroll', function() {
    tableScroll.scrollLeft(tableBody.scrollLeft());
    tableHeader.scrollLeft(tableBody.scrollLeft());
});

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var tableHeaderOffset = tableHeaderSpace.offset().top;
    if (this.pageYOffset >= tableHeaderOffset) {
        tableHeader.addClass('isFixed');
    } else {
        tableHeader.removeClass('isFixed');
    }
});
```

Again, this works great...but as you scroll right a bit more, the browser starts duplicating content within that fixed header:

[image]

The issue is is that no 'actual' content is being duplicated - this is some sort of browser fragmenting that is showing duplicates - without adding elements in the DOM.

The next picture is the browser doing some more "magic". at certain points in horizontal scrolling, the whole fixed header's colors gets inverted:

[image]

I wasn't able to get a snapshot of it, but it also once duplicated the "record count" bar below it.

Anyone have any ideas what's going on here? I tried to duplicate this in jsFiddle but no dice. From that, I would assume that this is an issue with my code, but the results are only with ONE specific browser on mac (safari), and it is doing some STRANGE stuff.

Last note - since I can't replicate this in jsFiddle, i'm not sure how I could report this to Apple (the working (or 'broken') example is proprietary and I can't give out access to it).

EDIT:
here's the jsfiddle where I tried to duplicate the issue (very rough - but it's functional):

[jsFiddle Duplication Attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/geoctrl/Ey44V/24/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so - I knew this wouldn't be a hot topic question, but I thought I would still give it a go ahead.

as for the answer, I found some old table css that was overlapping my new stuff - which in turn was somehow flipping safari out so bad that it was fragmenting it.

previous old code: `background: transparent;`

new code: `background: #fff;`

This doesn't make sense to me - but until someone else comes up with an hypothesis, I'll mark this as the answer.

now my number-one contender for worst browser: safari - look out, IE.